# Finding mutually exclusive pairs?

Tags: sqlite

there is a table "Likes" with fields "ID1" and "ID2" where there is mutually exclusive pairs , i want to find them 
i tried it by concatenation and it didn't work , i can't figure out why
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h04Qf.png)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data an desired results.

Comment: Add a DML too. `:)`

Comment: Are you using SQLite or MySQL? Why is this tagged with both systems?

Comment: I've edited my question , and sorry for tagging mysql .. It's sql lite

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would use `GROUP BY [column]` in combination with `HAVING COUNT([column|*]) >= [number]` to find duplicates within a column

```
SELECT 
 name
FROM 
 Highschooler 
GROUP BY
 name
HAVING 
 COUNT(*) >= 2
ORDER BY
 name ASC
```

If you need more information about the highschooler you need to JOIN again.

```
SELECT 
 Highschooler.*
FROM (

    SELECT 
     name
    FROM 
     Highschooler 
    GROUP BY
     name
    HAVING 
     COUNT(*) >= 2
    ORDER BY
     name ASC
)
 AS name_duplicated
INNER JOIN 
 Highschooler 
ON
 name_duplicated.name = Highschooler.name
```

Comment: i've edited my question ... Thank u

Answer (score 0):

If I've correctly interpreted your question, you can do like that:

```
SELECT name
FROM highschooler
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

It returns all names who occours are more than once in the `highschooler` table

Comment: i've edited my question ... Thank u

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find duplicate pairs but in any order, there are possibly many ways to do it.  Here's one:

```
create table likes(id1,id2);
insert into likes values
(1689,1709),
(1709,1689),
(1782,1709),
(1911,1247),
(1247,1468),
(1641,1468),
(1316,1304),
(1501,1934),
(1934,1501),
(1025,1101);

select min(id1,id2)||'-'||max(id1,id2) as pairs
  from likes
  group by pairs
  having count(*) > 1;
```